# Speeding up the Chrome App Development Process

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

Currently, my development process is:
1. zipping my code 
2. uploading it at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard, clicking publish
3. repeatedly clicking on "update extenstions now" at chrome://extensions/ to update the app which can take up to 60 minutes.

Is there a better way to do this? Waiting upto 60 minutes make dev very slow.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't [load it directly from the folder](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab_basics#developer-mode) on your computer?

Comment: i never knew you could do that. Thats the answer. If you put it as the answer then will tick it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab_basics#developer-mode) shows how to use developer mode to quickly load and launch your app/extension without having to finalize a distribution package:

1. Open `chrome://extensions` from the Chrome omnibox or via Settings
   and enable `[x] Developer mode` check box.

   [image: screenshot]
2. Drag'n'drop your app/extension folder onto the `chrome://extensions` page
   or click `Load unpacked extension` and choose your app/extension folder

   [image: screenshot]
3. Click `Launch` or use Chrome App Launcher