# How to test a test build of Chrome Extension on Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension

Since Chrome on Windows now removes non-Web Store extensions, how do we test an extension that's a test build? We have an extension that accesses a web service, i.e. the test build accesses the test web service and the production build that will be on the Chrome Web Store accesses the production web service.

Comment: Load it as an [unpacked extension in developer mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289697/)?

Comment: @wOxxOm That's hard to automate.

Comment: @Xan. Could you tell me why that is hard to automate?

Comment: Loading an unpacked extension will generate a warning on Chrome launch, that cannot be interacted with, say, Selenium.